# Same query executed in sequence, same execution time?

Tags: caching, postgresql-9.4

I was measuring execution time of one query to my locally hosted Postgresql 9.4. I did it in sequence in Java application (JDBC) and made 100 runs in loop. Whole loop was made in one connection.
Everytime the query took about 10 seconds to execute.
I use default postgresql.conf with one modification:
shared_buffers = 4GB
I got 16GB of RAM, OS is Debian 9.
Why is that query not cached?

Comment: Where's the query? Where's the execution plan? Where's the autotrace / analyzed explained plan?

Comment: Postgres does not cache "queries" (or the result of them). It only caches data blocks. Most probably all the needed blocks were already cached before you ran your test. Generating the execution plan using `explain (analyze, buffers)` will show you how many blocks were retrieved from the cache